# fulllcalendar-angular How to update one event in eventSource after drag and drop?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I am using @fullcalendar/angular v4.2 and have successfully created the calendar and use eventSources to get data via my backend API. I have been unable to figure out how to handle dragging an event to a new date in the month view.

```
<full-calendar #calendar
               defaultView="dayGridMonth"
               [editable]="true"
               [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
               [eventSources]="eventSources"
               (eventDrop)="onEventDrop($event)"
               (eventResize)="onEventResize($event)"></full-calendar>
```

When the drop event triggers I update my backend with the new time by adding the duration eventDropInfo delta to the previous start/end of my object stored in the extendedProps. However if I do nothing else, the calendar event just snaps back to its original position after I release the mouse. I added a call to calendarApi.refetchEvents() which reloads all the events and then the calendar draws the moved event in the new location. However this is not optimal, because the event snaps back to the original position while the new data is fetched, then it moves to the new position.

```
  public onEventDrop(eventDropInfo) {

    const form = eventDropInfo.event.extendedProps.form as SippForm;

    const duration = moment.duration(eventDropInfo.delta);
    const mStart = moment(form.DateStarted, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').add(duration.asSeconds(), 'seconds');
    const mEnd = moment(form.DateEnded, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').add(duration.asSeconds(), 'seconds');

    form.DateStarted = mStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    form.DateEnded = mEnd.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

    this.sippBackendService.updateSippForm(form)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(newForm => {
        const calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
        calendarApi.refetchEvents();
      }, error => {
        window.alert(`Changes couldn't be saved`);
        eventDropInfo.revert();
      });

  }
```

I would like the event to drop at its new location and then I update the backend API and the event stays where it dropped. What am I missing?

Attempt fix #1:

Based on https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/issues/184 I downgraded the versions

```
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.0.2-beta",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.0.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.0.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.0.1",
```

and now dragging works correctly for a fixed array of events. However when I try to use eventSources it throws a console error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
    at Calendar.options.<computed> (fullcalendar-angular.js:230)
```

Edit: Clarified using v 4.2
Edit: Tried downgrading

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're using fullCalendar 3.9?? Because most of your code shouldn't work at all if you are. e.g. The eventDrop function in 3.9 has quite a different signature which would make most of your onEventDrop code fail: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventDrop . The way you're using it looks more like the way it's done in v4 or v5 (e.g. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/eventDrop)

Comment: Hmm....Then I guess @fullcalendar/angular is installing its own version of fullcalendar. The package.json has 4.2 for @fullcalendar/angular but 3.9.0 for fullcalendar. I don't maintain the full app so I'm not sure why it is like that.

Comment: Are you using the Angular component provided by fullCalendar? i.e. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/angular ? If so then yes it will have downloaded another version of fullCalendar I'm sure, because it's a dependency. I'm not an Angular/npm user myself but I'd expect it to depend on a specific version or minimum version, and the fullCalendar Angular component wasn't introduced until fullCalendar v4 was released, so it must require at least that version.

Comment: I'm still perplexed by the behavior. I've used Fullcalendar js without trouble, not sure if I am forgetting something or what.

Comment: I agree, it's a bit odd. I made a quick demo using vanilla fullCalendar (v4) and can't reproduce it. Are you getting any console errors or anything?

Answer (score 0):

It appears @fullcalendar/angular is fairly sensitive to version mismatches. I was able to install these versions and it would work correctly:

```
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "4.1.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "4.1.0",
```

and

```
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "4.4.2",
```

Other combinations would not work.